# Android : How to populate fragment dynamically in a recycler layout adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i am trying to have a Recycler view in the form of a list view and i want to set a fragment to show more details under the list

this is my adapter layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id ="@+id/relative_layout_text"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_food_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view_food_image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_text"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and heres how i initiate my fragment in the adapter

```
public class FirebaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FirebaseAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private View views ;
    private List<Foods> FoodArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext ;
    private ArrayList<String> itemsDesc = new ArrayList<>();

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title,name;
    public ImageView foodImage;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public FrameLayout frameLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        foodImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_food_image);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_text);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragments);
        views = view;
    }
}

public FirebaseAdapter(Context context,List<Foods> Foods){
    this.FoodArray = Foods;
    this.mContext = context;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.menu_list, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(FoodArray.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.name.setText(FoodArray.get(position).getName());



    itemsDesc.add(FoodArray.get(position).getTitle());
    itemsDesc.add(FoodArray.get(position).getName());
    itemsDesc.add(FoodArray.get(position).getURL());

    DownloadImage Downloader = new DownloadImage(holder.foodImage);

    Downloader.execute(FoodArray.get(position).getURL());

    setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);


    Fragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("Food",itemsDesc);
    blankFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(holder.frameLayout.getId(),blankFragment,"BlankFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

//this is to download async
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView imageView){
            this.mImageView = imageView;
        }

        //this is the code for downloading the image
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String ... url){
            Bitmap Image = null;
            try{
                InputStream is = new URL(url[0]).openStream();
                Image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException ex ){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Image;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)
{
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (position > lastPosition)
    {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(viewToAnimate.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount(){return FoodArray.size();}   

}
```

and heres the code for my fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,container,false);
        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        TextView description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
        ImageView foodImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view_big_food_image);


        ArrayList<String> foods = getArguments().getStringArrayList("Food");

        title.setText(foods.get(0));
        description.setText(foods.get(1));

        DownloadImage Downloader = new DownloadImage(foodImage);

        Downloader.execute(foods.get(2));

        return view;
    }

    public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView imageView){
            this.mImageView = imageView;
        }

        //this is the code for downloading the image
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String ... url){
            Bitmap Image = null;
            try{
                InputStream is = new URL(url[0]).openStream();
                Image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException ex ){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

So with my current code i am expecting the data to be like this

[image: Expected results]

But i got this instead

[image: this is what i got]

so i am unsure on how to make it so i can get my expected results

Please and thanks and advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found my problem and there's no solution to this as the answer stated in this person question in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046940/fragments-as-a-recyclerviews-viewholder) he stated that initializing a fragment in the onBindView is possible but you can't do it if you're gonna use only one specific id as the fragment will stack on it instead of adding one on each recycler item

Comment: Don't use Fragments. What you drew looks like a CardView

Comment: @cricket_007 okay i am new to android development and i though fragment would do it

Comment: Fragments might be able to displayed into a List, but it wouldn't be very performant to use them that way